# Запуск Gulp task

Tags: javascript, gulp

Не могу разобраться как обновлять `index.min.js` при изменениях в `script.js`, но не трогать те файлы в которых не было изменений. Есть таск

```js
gulp.task('scripts', function(){
 return gulp.src([
  'src/assets/libs/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
  'src/assets/js/script.js'
 ])
 .pipe(concat('index.min.js'))
 .pipe(uglify())
 .pipe(gulp.dest('src/assets/js')); 
});
```

Есть вотчер

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch('src/assets/css/**/*.*', gulp.series('styles')).on('unlink', 
  function(filepath) {
   remember.forget('styles', path.resolve(filepath));
 });
 gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', gulp.series('assets'));
});
```

Если добавляю в вотчер по аналогии со стилями строку

```js
gulp.task('watch', function() {
 gulp.watch('src/assets/css/**/*.*', gulp.series('styles')).on('unlink', 
  function(filepath) {
   remember.forget('styles', path.resolve(filepath));
 });
  gulp.watch('src/assets/js/**/*.*', gulp.series('scripts')).on('unlink', 
  function(filepath) {
   remember.forget('scripts', path.resolve(filepath));
 });
 gulp.watch('src/**/*.*', gulp.series('assets'));
});
```

То скрипты обновляются после `Второй` перезагрузки браузера и в консоли постоянно выполняются таск `scripts` и `assets`

```js
gulp.task('assets', function() {
 return gulp.src(['src/**'], {since: gulp.lastRun('assets')})
  .pipe(newer('dist'))
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, я запутался)

Comment: Если нигде не хранить промежуточные обработанные версии всех файлов, то, скорее всего никак. Теоретически, есть возможность собирать итоговый файл не c concat, а с inject.